# Normalize node property cypher linear and log

Tags: cypher, normalization

Just when I thought I had understood the basics of cypher ....
I would like to create 2 new properties of a node and set a normalized value and a log normalized value based on an existing property that contains an integer, (call it count).  Setting the properties is easy.  I am having problems calculating them.

So I tried (first with a linear normalization)

```
match (n:MYLABEL) where n.count > 0
with n
set n.count_n = n.count/max(n.count)
```

When I run

```
match (n:MYLABEL) where n.count > 0 return max(n.count)
```

I get the largest nr of count.  But if I run

```
match (n:MYLABEL) where n.count > 0 return  n.count, max(n.count)
```

I get the same values for n.count and max(n.count).  So I realized max needs to operate on a list of all counts.  So I tried

```
  match (n:MYLABEL) where n.count > 0  
  with n, collect(n.count) as cl
  return  n.count, max(cl)
```

and I STILL get a count and [count] as output (same value).  I think I am missing something fundamental here.  Can anyone assist with what the cypher would look like for linear and log normalization? Grateful for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Andrew Bowman @neo4j
The short answer is

```
MATCH (n:MYLABEL) 
WHERE n.count > 0
WITH max(n.count) as maxCount
MATCH (n:MYLABEL) 
WHERE n.count > 0
SET n.count_n = n.count/maxCount
```

A different approach is

```
MATCH (n:MYLABEL) 
WHERE n.count > 0
WITH max(n.count) as maxCount, collect(n) as nodes
UNWIND nodes as n
SET n.count_n = n.count/maxCount
```

The reason of my misunderstanding:
the grouping key provides context for what you're aggregating over. n.count was the grouping key. So per that value, you asked for the max of that value, which is itself.
You need to remove that as the grouping key so max () is calculated with respect to all results. So either remove it completely, or collect () the values (it would become an aggregation term so not part of the grouping key), then UNWIND it back to rows afterwards.